# How can I monitor journald to invoke a program on a condition?

Tags: debian, logging, rsyslog, journald, journalctl

Before I reinvent the wheel and start scripting, is there a simple way (or existing tool) that can watch the systemd journal and take actions when certain log entries or conditions are detected?

Examples: Send an email if an error was logged in the last twenty minutes or record the IP address of a failed login attempt in a MySQL database.

Something like:

```
IF: `journalctl -p err --since "20 min ago"` IS NOT EMPTY
THEN: `journalctl -p err --since "20 min ago" |
       sed '1!b;s/^/To: errors@domain.com\n
       Subject: Errors in the last 20 minuites\n\n/' |
       sendmail -t
```

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com.  As a concept for parsing log files (and the systemd journal) and taking action on logged events:  
  - **`fail2ban`** is one such product (with `backend = systemd`) and although typically the action is adding a firewall rule, other actions can be selected. 

- The good old **`logwatch`** supports journalctl and is  commonly used to send e-mail  reports based on log file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this for multiple servers, because serverfault is about managing servers in a business environment.

It might be a overkill for you, but I would recommend taking a look at log collection tool like graylog.

You could also use journal-brief
https://github.com/twaugh/journal-brief

This can be run from cron to get a briefing of journal entries sent by email. Example:

```
cat /etc/cron.daily/journal-brief
#!/bin/sh
exec journal-brief -p err
```